# how can i fetch all data in column emp_finger when form load?

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

```
 mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection
 mysqlconn.ConnectionString = ("server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=emp_d")

 Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * from emp.t ", mysqlconn)
 Dim MemStream As IO.MemoryStream
 Dim fpBytes As Byte()
 Dim rdr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
 rdr.Read()
 mysqlconn.Open()

 fpBytes = rdr("emp_FRight")
 MemStream = New IO.MemoryStream(fpBytes)
 Dim template As New DPFP.Template(MemStream)
 OnTemplate(template)

 rdr.Close()
 mysqlconn.Close()
```

It only reads the first row in the column.
please help thankyou

Comment: The SQL is reading all columns from all rows.  Your code is just getting the data from the first row.  see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/

Comment: do i need to do looping to read all the fingerprint inside the emp_finger ??

thanks , sorry im having hard time with this problem